# Client Html cannot post to api ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http-post, backend

my api is not taking data from client sided code to the /api enpoint I have created on the localhost of the webserver on port 3000. How do I get it to take the server sided code to take the post request and console.log(request); correctly if it `Page started
(index):23 POST https://goldengates.club:3000/api net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(anonymous) @ (index):23
goldengates.club/:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch`

Client Sided Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        console.log("Page started");
            const num1=1;
            const num2=2;
            const data=35;//{num1,num2};
            const options =
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers:
                {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },

                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            };
            fetch('https://goldengates.club:3000/api'/*'https://goldengates.club/Cypher-Network/fetchTest.js'*/,options);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

server sided code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(3000,()=>console.log('listening on port 3000'));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/api',(request,response)=>
{
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");response.send({ statusCode:200, customMessage : 'Sucess', status : true })

    console.log(request);
    response.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the function [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) returns a promise, in order to use it, you need to call the [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) method, like so:

```
// backend code
app.post('/example', (req, res) => res.json({ data: 'abc' }));
```

```
// frontend code
fetch('/example', { method: 'post' }).then(r => r.json()).then(d => alert(d.data));
```

I think the way you show in your code, it will just store the function of how to compute the result of promise, not execute it and produce actual result (data fetched and passed to alert). With the `Promise.then` method, you can pass data the way you were doing, with `Content-Type: application/json` header and `body: JSON.stringify(object)`.

Comment: hello, I tried doing what you suggested but my req parameter is not defined it says.

Comment: client sided ```console.log("Page started");
            const num1=1;
            const num2=2;
            const data=35;//{num1,num2};
            fetch('https://goldengates.club:3000/api', { method: 'post' }).then(r => r.json()).then(d => alert(d.data));```

Comment: server sided code ```const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(3000,()=>console.log('listening on port 3000'));
app.use(express.static('public'));

/*app.post('/api',(request,response)=>
//{
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");response.send({ statusCode:200, customMessage : 'Sucess', status : true })*/
    app.post('/api', (req, res) => res.json({ data: 'abc' }));
    
    console.log(req);
    response.end();
//});```

Comment: error log ```fetchTest.js:11
    console.log(req);
                ^

ReferenceError: req is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/fetchTest.js:11:17)```

Comment: yes req is undefined, i am assuming you wanted to print the object from the `app.post('/api'` right before it, but you close the function. is should be `=> { res.json` instead of `=> res.json`. that way you have multiple statements in your arrow function

Comment: Thanks for your reply back, but it is still giving me that error, req is not defined and I don't see how.  client sided code- ```console.log("Page started"); 
        const num1=1; 
        const num2=2; 
        const data=35;//{num1,num2};
        
        
        fetch('https://goldengates.club:3000/api', { method: 'post' }).then(r => r.json()).then(d => alert(d.data));```

Comment: server sided- ```const express = require('express'); 
const app = express(); 
app.listen(3000,()=>console.log('listening on port 3000')); 
app.use(express.static('public')); 
app.post('/api', (req, res) =>  {res.json({ data: 'abc' })}); 
console.log(res); 
response.end();``` what I want to do is just print the request that it got from the client side to the console when running server sided code